# Vistas - base de datos en mariadb

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb, vistas

> Buenos tardes, en mi base de datos cree algunas vistas (no las pude poner aqui porque me marca que es mucho codigo y no me permite publicar la pregunta) pero ya no se me ocurren mas si alguien puede ayudarme con algunas vistas, se lo agradezco de antemano.

Tablas de mi base de datos:

```
create table recepcionista(Clav_re varchar(10) not null,
 Nombre_re varchar(20) not null,
 A_pre varchar(30) not null,
 A_mre varchar(30) not null,
 telefono varchar(15) not null,
primary key(Clav_re));



create table cliente(Id_cli varchar(10) not null,
Clav_re varchar(10) not null,
Nombre_cli varchar(25) not null,
A_pcli varchar(25) not null,
A_mcli varchar(25) not null,
Telefono_cli varchar(15) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Id_cli),
index(Clav_re),
FOREIGN KEY(Clav_re)
REFERENCES recepcionista(Clav_re)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

create table servicio (
Id_ser varchar(10) not null,
Tipo_ser varchar(25) not null,
Fecha date not null,
primary key(Id_ser));



create table cliSer (
Id_cli varchar(10),
Id_ser varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Id_cli,Id_ser),
INDEX (Id_cli),
INDEX(Id_ser),
FOREIGN KEY(Id_cli) REFERENCES cliente(Id_cli)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(Id_ser) REFERENCES servicio(Id_ser)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

create table habitacion (
Id_hab varchar(10) not null,
Id_cli varchar(10) not null,
Num_hab int(10) not null,
Num_piso int(10) not null,
Dias int(10) not null,
Precio int(10) not null,
Tip_hab varchar(20) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Id_hab),
index(Id_cli),
FOREIGN KEY(Id_cli)
REFERENCES cliente(Id_cli)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Esas son las tablas de mi base de datos asi las tengo ingresadas en mi consola ya que yo para crear las base de datos las hago desde el cmd de Windows y utilizo mariadb.

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error?

Comment: No no hay error, solo quiero que si porfavor alguien tiene mas ideas para crear mas vistas

Comment: tu pregunta no es clara, además si pides ideas entonces sería basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre, recuerda leer [ask], trata algo [aqui esta la doc. oficial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-view/) y si tienes errores edita tu publicación con ellos y con gusto te ayudamos, ya que la creación de las vistas depende de que tratas de obtener

Comment: Yo pregunto, ¿por qué quieres crear tantas vistas? ¿Has estudiado cuál es la utilidad de las vistas, en cuáles casos se recomienda usarlas y en cuáles no? ¿Acaso crees que una vista es un elemento mágico para llamarlo y ya, evitándote así la escritura de consultas? Pregunto todo esto porque intuyo que estás pensando las vistas como sustitutos de las consultas y esa no es su finalidad. Demasiadas vistas, eso es muyyy sospechoso, más aún si estás empezando con SQL.

Comment: Entiendo muchas gracias Aprendiz

Comment: Si apenas estamos empezando en las base de datos, solo que fue una tarea que pidió un profesor, pidió 15 vistas

Comment: Bueno, pues escríbele 15 vistas si eso es lo que pidió. Combina las tablas que tienen relación por ejemplo. Hazle una vista sobre los clientes cuyo apellido empieza por `A`, una vista de los negocios que están en la ciudad tal, de los clientes masculinos, de los clientes femeninos, de los clientes mayores de 50 años, de los clientes que compraron un monto superior a tal cantidad, de las habitaciones con más ocupación durante un año, de las habitaciones menos ocupadas durante los últimos 5 años, etc, etc.

Comment: si claro, muy buenas ideas, muchas gracias